# Online antivirus webapp?

Tags: webapp-rec, security

I was wondering whether there's any webapp that allows you to upload a suspicious file and have it diagnosed without having to install anything locally.

I'm fed up with the performance impact most of my AV software has had on my system and I've decided not to have any installed anymore, but there are situations when I'd like to double-check certain files.

A simple Google search didn't work for me, so I thought about asking here.

Comment: I removed your signature from the question.  Since your user box shows with your question, a signature as part of the question text is not needed.

Comment: Nice question, was thinking about it as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com/)

> VirusTotal.com is a website that provides free file checking. It uses up to 41 different antivirus products. Files can be sent either through the website or via email. The variety of products used by the website allows a user to check for viruses that the user's own antivirus solution may have missed, or to verify against false positives. The drawback to using VirusTotal is that it can only scan submitted files, and cannot perform system-wide scans on the user's computer. Another restriction users would face is that the size of the file uploaded or emailed to virustotal for scanning is up to 20 MB.

This site just uses different anti-virus engines to scan the file(s) you upload and tells you which engines detected the file as malware and which ones did not.

Answer (score 3):

Kaspersky has [an online tool](http://www.kaspersky.com/scanforvirus) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

BitDefender has an [online scanner](http://www.bitdefender.com/scanner/online/free.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Panda Active Scan 2
[System Scan](http://www.pandasecurity.com/activescan/index/)  - for Quick or Full System Scan
[Other Scan](http://www.pandasecurity.com/activescan/other_scan/) - for Specific folders or files

Comment: Panda is the first cloud antivirus http://www.cloudantivirus.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

Trend Micro's [HouseCall](http://housecall.trendmicro.com/).

Here are its requirements:

> Hardware At least 300MHz IntelTM
>   PentiumTM processor or equivalent At
>   least 256MB memory At least 200MB
>   available disk space
>
> Operating System Windows™ XP (32-bit)
>   Home or Professional with SP2 or SP3
>   Windows Vista™ (32-bit, 64-bit)
>   Ultimate, Business, Home Premium, or
>   Home Basic with SP1 or SP2 Windows 7
>   (32-bit, 64-bit)
>
> Display At least high-color (16-bit)
>   and a minimum resolution of 1024x768
>   pixels

It uses Java.